# accessing guest_user id in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm adding guest user functionality to my app using the guide detailed in the link here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

I've followed these steps and am now trying to access the guest in one of my controllers.  Since this controller inherits from `ApplicationController`, my thought process is I should be able to access the `guest_user` method like so

```
@user = guest_user
```

I'm doing this so I can then show the guest user's id in my views.  I did the skip_before_filter step in the controller method that the above code is inside.

When I try to run this I get the following error: `undefined method '[]' for false:FalseClass`.  I've been trying to find the problem but have been unsuccessful.

I tried commenting out the

```
u.save(false)
```

and the error became: `Couldn't find User without an ID` with the accompanying `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in [controller]`.  So I believe this means that the problem is occuring in `session[:guest_user_id]`?  Thanks in advance.

I'm using rails 3.1.1, formtastic 2.0.2, and devise 1.5.1

Comment: What does the backtrace say? What line of code is causing the problem?

Comment: @andrewpthorp it show the u.save(false) as causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I solved my own question apparently you have to change

```
u.save(false)
```

into

```
u.save(:validate => false)
```

I'm not sure why this is the case and the how to guide I linked above did not have this in there so I'll dig a bit deeper and see if I can find why this is needed for me.

Update: u.save(false) is the outdated version, in rails 3 use u.save(:validate => false)